# ubuntu 16.04 Kodi remove and install problem

Tags: dependencies

1st issue i had was after i installed kodi 17 on my ubuntu 16.4 asus laptop the audio literally screamed at me upon opening the app. so i removed and purged and tried to install a earlier version kodi.
 now i get this response from the terminal:
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kodi : Depends: kodi-bin (< 2:16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial.1~) but 2:17.1~git20170320.2031-final-0xenial is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: i did a google search 2:17.1~git20170320.2031-final-0xenialand and performed a sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/unstable and
sudo apt-get update i then did a sudo apt-get install kodi this time it installed without errors.   i am back go my original problem of the audio blasting a screaming noise upon opening kodi.

Comment: i would like to try again to remove the kodi 17 and install a earlier version but i will see if there is a fix to the audio issue first

Comment: I solved it. i found a wiki on Ubuntu binary add-ons and installed the top three Audio decoder add-on packages logic was perhaps one of them would fix it i also found on the same page a ADSP package in the example and installed it example: sudo apt-get install kodi-pvr-argust after that i opened the kodi app and tested it and it works great. sorry i know you guys would have helped out but i didn't want to wait.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)